# How to c# several accurate timers (exactly for 10 milliseconds interval)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, timer, elapsedtime

I've started the  a desktop app development in C# (VS2010 .Net Fw 4.0) involving several timers.

At first, I was using **System.Timers** in order to send data by USB to a data bus. My point is that I need to send different periodic binary messages with several specific intervals of time such as 10ms, 20ms, 40ms, 100ms, 500ms, 1000ms ....

In each timer I have a callback function who has to send the correct data flow for each raised event.

The problem is when I have the full amount of signals working, the real interval is different than expected (3000ms raises to 3500, 100ms to 340) because when I add the 10ms to 40ms timers, the cpu is overload almost 100% and loses all the precission.

I'm working in VMWare with 2GB RAM and 2CPU cores. The Host machine is an i7-2600K CPU @ 3,40GHz. I think this is no the problem.(but I think).

Before I wrote here, i was looking for an answer about how to be more exact with timing,  using the most optimized resource consumption. but all I found it was unespecific.

I already knows about **System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch** reading about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsedmilliseconds%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but this class have not events. Also **System.Windows.Forms.Timer** but is more imprecise, and with low resolution.

There is a good implementation [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/98346/Microsecond-and-Millisecond-NET-Timer) with microseconds resolution but it is the reason of my overloading CPU!

What do you think about my further steps!? I'll appreciate any help or idea you have

10% timing resolution is the goal in 10ms' interval!

I will clarify any extra info you need!

Comment: The desktop version of Windows is not a real-time operating system. If you have strict real-time requirements then use a real-time operating system; otherwise you will be fighting the assumptions of the operating system. You should consider purchasing specialized hardware if you have strict real-time requirements.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2989350/62576

Comment: You can't.  The resolution will never be that accurate in an application in Windows / not at a hardware / driver level.

Comment: To add to the confusion [Precision is not the same as accuracy](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/09/02/459952.aspx)

Comment: I found  [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17474/Timer-surprises-and-how-to-avoid-them) a good application in c# to test your SO capacity for timing.
In my Virtual Machine the **Native Multimedia Timers** really has an average interval of 1msec.